# firefox: refresh content in a div, but the outside textbox also cleared its content, why?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I use jQuery ajax to call a function periodly in order to get latest new store in database. I use a div to display the data tracking from database, however, whenever the div got refreshed, a textbox which outside  tag also got refreshed and the content just disappear. I only find this happened in firefox, everything works in IE. Does anyone know why and how to resolve this issue?

```
setInterval("Get()", 2000);
function Get() {
        var nickName='<%=nickName %>';
        var from = '<%=to %>';
        var time = '<%=insertTime %>';
        $.post('AjaxPages/Chat.aspx', { "type": "get", "from": from,"nickName":nickName, "insertTime": time }, function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#contentDIV').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

User control HTML(I think might use it as a control so won't double my work in future, the user control is embeded in an empty webpage and called by using $.load() in another webpage):

```
<table style="border-style: double; border-width: 1px;width:200px;height:250px">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="contentDIV" style="overflow-y:auto;height:100%;width:200px;">

    </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the `div`. This is invalid HTML. Use this:

```
<div id="contentDIV" style="overflow-y:auto;height:100%;width:200px;">
</div>

<input id="Text1" type="text" />
```

Comment: In my application, it does have </div> before textbox tag

Comment: @Steven Zack Can you then post some more of your HTML? Rr, for that matter, the HTML being returned from the AJAX request?

Comment: Not html, just data in div returned from AJAX